# Flutter: How to set conditions for dynamic data (String, int, double) from Json

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON like this [(link API)](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tft-test-48c87.appspot.com/o/value.json?alt=media&token=b1dc8e5d-1ffb-4389-9799-c57e335fb7c2)

```
[
  {
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "value": 12.0
  },
  {
    "value": "twelve"
  }
]
```

How to set data conditions to:

- If value is `int` then => `Text('Int ${_value[i].value.toString()}')`
- If value is `double` then => `Text('Double ${_value[i].value.toString()}')`
- If value is `String` then =>
  `Text('String ${_value[i].value}')`

to be displayed as the image below
[image]

so pls help me, this is the model file:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Value> valueFromJson(String str) => List<Value>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Value.fromJson(x)));

String valueToJson(List<Value> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Value {
  Value({
    this.value,
  });

  dynamic value;

  factory Value.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Value(
    value: json["value"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "value": value,
  };
}
```

and this is main file:

```
import 'package:ask/model/value_model.dart';
import 'package:ask/services/value_services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page4 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page4State createState() => _Page4State();
}

class _Page4State extends State<Page4> {
  List<Value> _value = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ValueServices.getValue().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _value = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Value')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < _value.length; i++)
            // How to set Conditions here
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the getTimeType property with a ListView.builder. A for loop wouldn't work.

```
body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _value.length,
        builder: (context, pos){
                    var typeName = getTypeName(_value[pos]['value]).toString();
                    return Text("$typeName $_value[pos]['value]");
                  }
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, you can check if a dynamic value is a double or an integer by using the is keyword and the double and int types

Here's an example:

```
dynamic myValue = 10;

if (myValue is int) {
  print('myValue is an integer');
} else if (myValue is double) {
  print('myValue is a double');
} else {
  print('myValue is not an integer or a double');
}
```